# Is it possible to track requests within the GCP load balancer similar to AWS ELB?

Tags: amazon-web-services, google-cloud-platform, load-balancing, devops, trace

I noted that within AWS you can trace requests at the Load Balancer which is useful for unique identification. Within Google Cloud Platform it appears that we are limited to several variables which doesn't provide a unique ID.

Is anyone using GCP and implementing a unique ID?

Sources:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/application/load-balancer-request-tracing.html

https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/user-defined-request-headers

Comment: I am not aware of a GCP method similar to AWS. However, you can add any valid header you want to your client requests and then log the header and extra data to Stackdriver at your backend. Can you expand on what you are trying to accomplish?

Comment: Thanks, I will look into the stackdriver options but the high-level goal is to trace a request end to end. We would want the information in there by default, without relying on the browser to insert it into a header for every request.

Comment: I am not sure what "end-to-end" means with GCP services in your use case. You have a load balancer and backends (Compute Engine and/or Cloud Storage). That is it unless you add more services yourself - such as a data layer. There is no path for you to trace before that. Technically, there are but these are services you cannot see (GFE for example). Stackdriver messages already have an ID. Have you checked to see if that ID is suitable? If you can edit your question with more information, maybe there is something that I am misunderstanding in your use case.

Comment: Sure, by end to end we mean that we want to have a unique connection / request id assigned at the firewall or load balancer (most likely the load balancer because the firewall likely doesn’t operate at layer 7) that’s passed through the target proxy as a header, e.g. X-Correlation-Id, so we can track a request from the earliest possible point it enters our system all the way through the miscellaneous services that may handle the operation. I am looking into the stackdriver option, thanks.

Comment: You could try to look into the Stackdriver logs viewer. The logs viewer will give you a huge amount of information, but you can find the specific line you need and create a filter to only similar info. Make sure to first select the LB you want to review before creating the filter.

Answer (score 5):

According to https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/https#target-proxies the load balancer will set an `X-Cloud-Trace-Context` header which should meet your needs. It's intended for use with [Cloud Trace](https://cloud.google.com/trace) but the identifier is sufficiently unique that you could use it separately as well, if you prefer not to use Cloud Trace for this purpose.